# created a simple middleware game with Nodejs, and an http header error occurs

Tags: node.js

I am a beginner studying Nodejs.

I have recently studied node middleware and have created a simple game using middleware.

The purpose of the generated code is to respond to hello by connecting as root and then respond to the browser with 50% probability through the middleware.

However, I get the following error:

I did a search and found that res.send is not available after next ().

Is that correct?

But I could not figure out why and I did not realize why the code did not work.

**code**

```
const express = require('express');

var app = express();

app.use('/', (req, res, next) =>{
    res.send('hello');
    next();
});

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    if (+new Date() % 2 === 0) {
        console.log('continue');
        res.send('lucky!');
        next();
    } else {
        console.log('failed');
        res.send('end');
    }
});

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    if (+new Date() % 2 === 0) {
        console.log('continue');
        res.send('lucky!');
        next();
    } else {
        console.log('failed');
        res.send('end');
    }
});

app.listen(3000, () => console.log(`Example!`))
```

**error**

```
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const express = require('express');

var app = express();

app.use(/^\/$/, (req, res, next) =>{
    res.send('hello');
    return;
});

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    if (+new Date() % 2 === 0) {
        console.log('continue');
        res.send('lucky!');
        next();
    } else {
        console.log('failed');
        res.send('end');
    }
});


app.listen(3000, () => console.log(`Example!`))
```

you cannot use `res.send()` twice
res.send() = `Sends the HTTP response`.